# Subquery on timestampdiff only allows for 1 result, how do I scale this for all results?

Tags: subquery, mysql-5.6

I'm currently writing up a query which is meant to output data to show curves of power profiles, and I'm facing a slight problem. So far, I've managed to do this:

```
select datetime, PLANT_STATUS, INCOMER_PWR, PLANT_DEMAND, PLANT_OUTPUT
from d909 
where 
    (PLANT_STATUS >=400 AND PLANT_STATUS < 500) 
    OR 
    (timestampdiff(minute, 
                   (select min(datetime) 
                    from d909 
                    where PLANT_STATUS >= 400 AND PLANT_STATUS < 500
                   ), 
                   datetime) 
         <= -1
     ) 
     OR 
     (timestampdiff(minute, 
                    (select max(datetime) 
                     from d909 
                     where PLANT_STATUS >= 400 AND PLANT_STATUS < 500
                    ), 
                    datetime) 
         >= 1
     );
```

How do I get the timestampdiff functions to resolve for ANY data, not just the min and max? I realise subqueries normally have 1 row, but I would like to have multiple rows output from it.

Comment: Did you write this existing query? I can't picture a data set that makes sense with this query.

Comment: It does pop up with a few responses, but going through them, it seems like a very odd set of data :(. All I'm trying to do is extract values from datetime (Primary key) where the plant is running in mode 400-499, and about a minute either side of those mode.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment try something like this I think

```
select datetime, PLANT_STATUS, INCOMER_PWR, PLANT_DEMAND, PLANT_OUTPUT
from d909 as d1
where 
    (PLANT_STATUS >=400 AND PLANT_STATUS < 500) 
UNION ALL
select datetime, PLANT_STATUS, INCOMER_PWR, PLANT_DEMAND, PLANT_OUTPUT
from d909 as d1
where (select COUNT(*) 
        from d909 as d2
        -- find all records within a minute of the first set of records
        where abs(DATEDIFF(MI,d2.datetime,d1.datetime)) <= 1
        -- not sure if this status check required
        AND (PLANT_STATUS >=400 AND PLANT_STATUS < 500) 
        ) > 1
AND (PLANT_STATUS >=400 AND PLANT_STATUS < 500)
```

Comment: I had to modify that a bit, since it was MySQL, DateDiff wasn't a function, but I modified it to timestampdiff(minute,...). It's been running for over 600 seconds now, seems to have hung there :/ Would this be normal?

Comment: Oops. And as I have no idea how large your DB, how efficient your design is or how spec'd your server I've no idea how long this should take. To be utterly frank though your desired result doesn't seem to make sense to me I'm afraid.